# How to shut down Spring application during configuration process?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the best practice to shutdown a Spring application during the configuration process or after the application context is initialized?

For example, in my case, I have several `@ConfigurationProperties` and at least one of them must be specified otherwise the application will shutdown. Should I use `@Conditional`, some general `@ConfigurationProperties` for validation, or something else?

---

### I decided to use Validation with general `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = AtLeastOneOfTheFieldsValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AtLeastOneOfTheFields {

    String message() default "At least one of the fields must be specified";

    String onBooleanCondition();

    String[] fields();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @interface List {

        AtLeastOneOfTheFields[] value();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AtLeastOneOfTheFieldsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AtLeastOneOfTheFields, Object> {

    private String[] fields;

    private String booleanConditionField;

    @Override
    public void initialize(AtLeastOneOfTheFields atLeastOneOfTheFields) {
        this.fields = atLeastOneOfTheFields.fields();
        this.booleanConditionField = atLeastOneOfTheFields.onBooleanCondition();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        Object booleanConditionValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(booleanConditionField);

        if (Objects.isNull(booleanConditionValue) || Objects.equals(Boolean.TRUE, booleanConditionValue)) {
                return Arrays.stream(fields)
                    .map(field -> new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(field))
                    .anyMatch(Objects::nonNull);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bot")
@Validated
@AtLeastOneOfTheFields(fields = {"facebook.page-access-token", "telegram.token", "viber.token"},
        onBooleanCondition = "enabled",
        message = "At leas one of bot token must be specified if property bot.enabled = 'true'.")
public class BotConfig {

    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private FacebookBotConfig facebook;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private TelegramBotConfig telegram;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ViberBotConfig viber;
}
```

---

### Another variant is use `ApplicationContextInitializer` to validate Enviroment properties.

I will be glad to your comments or advice. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can create some shutdown Handler component like this:

```
@Component
public class ShutdownHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void shutdown(int code) {     // to shutdown you have to put 0 number
        SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> code);
    }
}
```

And on your properties class, call it;

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Autowired
    private ShutdownHandler handler;

    public void someMethod() {            
        if (isValid){
           handler.shutdown(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I decided to use the validation mechanism.